# Javascript - Show div only with device is in landscape

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my script.

I am showing a hidden div `#alert` **only when** `#total=0`, and what I am looking for is that it **ONLY** be displayed when the screen is in landscape. (See CSS).

What is the snippet of the script to add, and which evaluates whether the screen is landscape?

See online **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p6yfx5t4/1)** ( JSFiddle ).

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function manageRegalo() {

    var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
    var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());

    if (totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
      total = totalStorage;
    }

    if (total > 99.99 && total < 299.99) {
      console.log("PASS");
      $('#regalo').show();
      $('#alert').hide();

      if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
        $('.tooltip').show();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 2000);

        //--------------------

        if (!$("#notify")[0].paused) { //play audio
          $("#notify")[0].pause(); //play audio
          $("#notify")[0].currentTime = 0; //play audio

        } else { // play audio
          setTimeout(function () { //play audio
            $("#notify")[0].play(); //play audio
          })
        }; //play audio

        //--------------------

        localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
      }

    } else if (!total) {
      $('#regalo').hide();
      $('#alert').show();
    } else {
      console.log("FAIL");
      $('#alert').hide();
      $('#regalo').hide();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
      manageRegalo();

      localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val()));
    }
  });
  manageRegalo();
});
```

**CSS:**

```css
  #alert,
  .tooltip {
    display: none
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:999px) and (orientation:landscape) {

    #alert {
      display: block;
    }
  }
```

**HTML:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regalo">Regalo</div>
<br>
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
<br>
<div id="alert">Alert</div>
<br>
<input type="text" id="total" value="">
<button type="button" class="bbp">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem basically  is here:

```
 var total = parseFloat($("#total").val());
```

and consequently here

```
 } else if (!total) {
      $('#regalo').hide();
      $('#alert').show();
```

The first time you read `total` it provides `NaN` and then the `else if (!total)` is executing `$('#alert').show();`

For that reason, you see `alert` message.

Comment: I get it. The script works very well, but I just want it to fulfill its function in landscape mode when #total=0

Comment: As I  understand you only want to so the alert when total is 0?